# Why won't Elm compile this HTTP request for JSON data example when the arguments are the same as working examples?

Tags: go, elm

I am working on a basic decoding-json Elm example for practice but can not figure out the Elm compilation errors. I also am confused why this runs in Ellie (that is with a remote JSON URL) but not when compiled locally using Elm v 19.0 FYI.

The goal was to make a simple call to get JSON from a Go server but just compiling the example Elm I got from the documentation for decoding JSON is not working out so here we are.

```
module HelloWorld exposing (..)


import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Http
import Json.Decode exposing (Decoder, field, string)



-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.element
    { init = init
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    , view = view
    }



-- MODEL


type Model
  = Failure
  | Loading
  | Success String


init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  (Loading, getRandomCatGif)



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = MorePlease
  | GotGif (Result Http.Error String)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    MorePlease ->
      (Loading, getRandomCatGif)

    GotGif result ->
      case result of
        Ok url ->
          (Success url, Cmd.none)

        Err _ ->
          (Failure, Cmd.none)



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ h2 [] [ text "Random Cats" ]
    , viewGif model
    ]


viewGif : Model -> Html Msg
viewGif model =
  case model of
    Failure ->
      div []
        [ text "I could not load a random cat for some reason. "
        , button [ onClick MorePlease ] [ text "Try Again!" ]
        ]

    Loading ->
      text "Loading..."

    Success url ->
      div []
        [ button [ onClick MorePlease, style "display" "block" ] [ text "More Please!" ]
        , img [ src url ] []
        ]



-- HTTP


getRandomCatGif : Cmd Msg
getRandomCatGif =
  Http.get
    { url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotGif gifDecoder
    }


gifDecoder : Decoder String
gifDecoder =
  field "data" (field "image_url" string)
```

and now the go server

```
// write json back to elm call

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type ToDo struct {
    Title       string
    Description string
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/test", test)

    http.ListenAndServe(getPort(), nil)

}

func getPort() string {
    p := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if p != "" {
        return ":" + p
    }
    return ":8080"
}

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        //Allow CORS here By * or specific origin
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        // say hi
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello from go"+"\n")

    } else {
        //Allow CORS here By * or specific origin
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        todo := readForm(r)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "updated todo to"+todo.Title+"\n")
    }
}

func readForm(r *http.Request) *ToDo {
    r.ParseForm()
    todo := new(ToDo)
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decodeErr := decoder.Decode(todo, r.PostForm)
    if decodeErr != nil {
        log.Printf("error mapping parsed form data to struct : ", decodeErr)
    }
    return todo
}
```

and finally the ELM errors 
elm make ./src/HelloWorld.elm

```
Detected problems in 1 module.
-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------------- src/HelloWorld.elm

Something is off with the body of the `getRandomCatGif` definition:

110|>  Http.get
111|>    { url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"
112|>    , expect = Http.expectJson GotGif gifDecoder
113|>    }

This `get` call produces:

    Decoder a -> Http.Request a

But the type annotation on `getRandomCatGif` says it should be:

    Cmd Msg

-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------------- src/HelloWorld.elm

The 1st argument to `get` is not what I expect:

110|   Http.get
111|>    { url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"
112|>    , expect = Http.expectJson GotGif gifDecoder
113|>    }

This argument is a record of type:

    { expect : b, url : String }

But `get` needs the 1st argument to be:

    String

-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------------- src/HelloWorld.elm

The 1st argument to `expectJson` is not what I expect:

112|     , expect = Http.expectJson GotGif gifDecoder
                                    ^^^^^^
This `GotGif` value is a:

    Result Http.Error String -> Msg

But `expectJson` needs the 1st argument to be:

    Decoder a

-- TOO MANY ARGS -------------------------------------------- src/HelloWorld.elm

The `expectJson` function expects 1 argument, but it got 2 instead.

112|     , expect = Http.expectJson GotGif gifDecoder
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Are there any missing commas? Or missing parentheses?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've installed version 1.0.0 of the `elm/http` module whereas the example requires `elm/http` version 2.0.0.  I could reproduce your errors with version 1.0.0 of this package, but the code compiled successfully with 2.0.0.

Edit your `elm.json` file to change the version of `elm/http` to `2.0.0` and try running `elm make ...` again.